# Combinatorics Inclusion-Exclusion problem with permutations and derangements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Let $n \ge$ 3 ($n \in \mathbb{N}$).

How many permutations $\sigma [n] \to [n]$ there are such that:

$\forall  i: \sigma (i) \ne i$,

$\sigma (1) = 2$,

$\sigma (2) = 3$.

I know that I'm supposed to use inclusion-exclusion, and clearly it has something to do with derangements.

I have problem calculating the cardinalities of the sets I define.
Can someone give me a guideline for the solution?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You are right we use derangement. 
Since f(1)=2 ; f(2) =3
For rest  f(i) is not I. ;;  Two case are possible CASE 1 ::  f(3) =1 then number of permutations are $$ D_{(n-3)} $$ I.e Derangement of rest n-3 objects at (n-3) places ;;

Case 2 ::  if f(3) is not 1 then $$ D_{(n-2)} $$

Total permutations are $$ D_{(n-3)} + D_{(n-2)}  $$

Comment: Typesetting tip.  To write $D_{n - 2}$, type `$D_{n - 2}$`.

Comment: Yes it is the same I mentioned

Comment: To reiterate N.F. Taussig's point, you have typeset your answer as a D, followed by a single open parenthesis in the subscript, followed by "n-2)" in line with the D.  This gives $$\large D_(n-2)$$ which looks awkward.  The only grouping operator LaTeX understands to create a single block is the curly braces { and } so you should always enclose multiple-character sub/super-scripts with the curly braces { } 
$$ \large \mbox{ D_{n-2} gives } \quad D_{n-2} \\ \large \mbox{ D_{(n-2)} gives } \quad D_{(n-2)} \\ \large \mbox{etc.}$$

Alternatively if you don't want subscripts, avoid using '_'

Comment: @mathsdiscussion.com Can you elaborate on case 2, i.e. providing a bijection between the derangements of case 2 and the derangements of $\{1, \dots, n-2\}$?

Comment: Assuming now the correct place of 3 is 1 that means in derangement  f(3) cannot be 1.

Comment: @mathsdiscussion.com I understand that. My question is to prove that the number of permutations of case 2 is equal to $D_{n-2}$. A good proof would be to provide a bijection between the set of permutations of case 2 and the set of derangements of $\{1,\dots,n-2\}$.

Comment: In case 2 ;  f(1) and f(2) are fixed and deranged but domain have 3 where as in codomain 3 do not exist and in domain now 1 is not available but 1 exist in codomain.  That means either 1,2,3 are deranged among themselves and rest n-3 among themselves as in case1 and from 4 to n none map with 1 in codomain.  2nd case ensure one from 4 to n can map with 1 in codomain and 3 with other it is possible if I assume correct place of 3 is 1

Comment: I still cant understand why case 2 is $D_{n-2}$

Comment: Just think in line how you ensure $$ f(3) \neq1$$

Comment: Oh so we just can call 1 in the range := 3, and then its just like finding the derangements right?

Comment: Yes absolutely I think now everything is absolutely clear

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net In case 2, each of the $n - 2$ elements larger than $2$ has one prohibited position.  For $3$, the prohibited position is $1$.  For each element larger than $3$, the prohibited element is itself.

Comment: I think you also meen the same that $ f(\,3\,)\neq{1} $